# virtual keyword in c#

Tags: c#, .net, oop, overriding, virtual

I have knowledge of Java and have been learning C# for the last couple of days. Now I have come across the "virtual" keyword which, as suggested at [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), is used to allow the corresponding methods, properties etc. to be overriden in the subclasses. Now I think we can override methods even without using the "virtual" keyword. Then why it is necessary?

Comment: "Now I think we can override methods even without using the 'virtual' keyword." You think?

Comment: @BoltClock Certainly. `abstract` in the base class and `override` in the derived class are enough. No need for `virtual` :P

Comment: Yes, virtual means "I'm providing an implementation, but you may polymorphically override it" and abstract means "I'm defining something you must provide an implementation for, which will act polymorphically". Unlike shadowing (which is generally considered to be sub-optimal), the function signatures must match.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Well, yeah ;)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need the `virtual` keyword if you really want to `override` methods in sub classes. Otherwise the base implementation will be hidden by the new implementation, just as if you had declared it with the `new` keyword.

Hiding the methods by "overriding" them without the base method being declared `virtual` leaves you without polymorphism, that means: if you "cast" a specialized version to the "base" version and call a method, always the base classes implementation will be used instead of the overridden version - which is not what you'd expect.

Example:

```
class A
{
    public void Show() { Console.WriteLine("A"); }
}

class B : A
{
    public void Show() { Console.WriteLine("B"); }
}

A a = new A();
B b = new B();

a.Show(); // "A"
b.Show(); // "B"

A a1 = b;
a1.Show(); // "A"!!!
```

Answer (score 9):

`virtual` is a way of defining that a method *has* a default implementation, but that that implementation may be overriden in a child class. Other than by using virtual, you cannot override a method directly without using the `new` keyword (which is generally bad practice).

A good example of the implementation of `virtual` is the `ToString()` method. Every object in C# is guaranteed to be able to call `ToString()` because every object inherits from the base `System.Object` class, which contains a virtual method `ToString()`. Derived classes can override this however, and provide their own implementation which may be more useful to the users of the object.

Update: I recently wrote a blog post which goes into this topic in a bit of depth. [Check it out here](https://www.levibotelho.com/development/polymorphism-with-new-and-override/).

Comment: I recently came across your comment here, and wanted to let you know that your link to the blog post seems to be broken. I was wondering if you can revive it for the late audience. thanks in advance.

Comment: @CesarB wow this is an old answer :). Updated the URL, hopefully the post is still relevant!

Answer (score 2):

> Now I think we can override methods even without using the "virtual" keyword.

No, you can't. Contrary to Java, in C# members are **sealed by default** and you cannot override them unless you marked them with the `virtual` keyword.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this example:

```
void Main()
{
    var obj1 = new Sub();
    Console.WriteLine(((Base)obj1).method1());
}

public class Base
{
    public virtual string method1()
    {
        return "method1 (from Base)";
    }
}

public class Sub : Base
{
    override public string method1()
    {
        return "overridden method1 (from Sub)";
    }
}
```

In this example the subclass `Sub` is instantiated and assigned to object variable `obj1`.
In the `Console.WriteLine` statement's parameter it is being cast into the base class `Base`, then method `method1` is called.
Because we have used `virtual` in the base class `Base` and `override` in the subclass `Sub`, we're getting

> overridden method1 (from Sub)

as output.

If you remove `virtual` in the method declaration of `method1` in `Base` and remove `override` in the method of subclass `Sub` as well, then you're getting

> method1 (from Base)

as output, which means that the cast also has the effect that the original declaration of method `method1` in the base class `Base` is used.

**N.B.** If you're using the `new` keyword in subclass `Sub`, such as

```
         new public string method1() {
            return "overridden method1";
        }
```

assuming that the `virtual` keyword in the base class `Base` is absent, you're getting the output

> method1 (from Base)

as well. If you would not cast it to `Base` (and keep the type as `Sub`), the new `method1` would be used, meaning it belongs to the class `Sub` where it is declared only - and hides the method's original declaration from the `Base` class at the same time. This is called *shadowing* (or *hiding*) a method.

**Summary:**

- To override a method, which should be effective also if you cast to the base class, use the `virtual` keyword in the base class and `override` in the sub class.
- If you intend to override the method, which should be active in the sub class only, use the `new` keyword in the sub classes method declaration. As you have seen it works also without it, but it is better if it is there so everyone knows that this is a new version of the method.

Answer (score 0):

virtual / override will allow the derived class to override the base function if the derived class is instantiated as the Base class.
Example:

```
      class A
      {
         public virtual void Show() { Console.WriteLine("A"); }
      }

      class B : A
      {
         public override void Show() { Console.WriteLine("B"); }
      }


         A a = new A();
         B b = new B();

         a.Show(); 
         b.Show(); 

         A a1 = b;
         a1.Show();  // here is the test!!!

         B b1 = new B();
         b.Show();  

With virtual / override :
A
B
B
B

After removing virtual / override keywords (or simply removing override):
A
B
A
B
```