# Generic Method issue/bug?

Tags: c#, generics

Can anyone explain me this issue?

the only way to get this working, is to use the virtual in the CorrectName and then override in the Derived one, instead of new keyword, but, WHY is this happening?

WHY if I cast by generic it gives me the Base value, and if I cast it directly it gives me Derived value?
((Output is below))

Thanks guys, as I've said you, I already got the "solution", but I want to **UNDERSTAND**

```
    class Base
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string CorrectName { get { return Name; } }
    }
    class Derived : Base
    {
        public new string CorrectName { get { return "NEW" + Name; } }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Derived> container = new List<Derived>();

        var d = new Derived() { Name = "NameDerived2" };

        container.Add(d);

        Search<Derived>(container);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void Search<T>(List<T> list) where T : Base
    {
        foreach (var el in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No Cast -->" + el.CorrectName);
            Console.WriteLine("Generic Cast -->" + (el as T).CorrectName);
            Console.WriteLine("Direct Cast -->" + (el as Derived).CorrectName);
        }
    }
```

OUTPUT:

```
No Cast -->NameDerived2

Generic Cast -->NameDerived2

Direct Cast -->NEWNameDerived2
```

TABLE OF TRUTH:

```
el is Derived == true
el.GetType().Equals(typeof(Derived)) == true
el.GetType().Equals(typeof(T)) == true
el.GetType().Equals(typeof(Base)) == false
typeof(T).Equals(typeof(Base)) == false
typeof(T).Equals(typeof(Derived)) == true
```

Comment: Because T is `Base` not `Derived` so essentially you are casting to `Base` not `Derived` - when you cast to `Derived` the property `CorrectName` is resolved to be the one marked `new` because it hides the original property on `Base` - this isn't an issue or a bug - what do you expect it to do??

Comment: T Inherit Base, but I'm passing Derived as T, so I'm casting to Derived, not Base

Comment: I thought this had to do with the fact that you're passing in a `List<T>`, but changing to just take a single `T` has the same results.  I think we need Eric Lippert or Jon Skeet to explain this.

Comment: No T is `Base` since you've constrained it to that. `Derived` inherits from `Base` so technically T *is* `Derived` in your generic class but the generic method doesn't know anything about `Derived` at design time so you could probably argue that it shoulnd't know about the `new` method on `Derived` or you open up to a world of hurt where `new` might break your expected behaviour (i.e. you don't mark the method virtual yet someone uses `new` and modifies your intended behaviour!). There are probably some special rules for this in the building of the generic class

Answer (score 4):

Without the `virtual` keyword, the method in the base class is not overridden, but "hidden" by the new implementation. You're also enforcing this by using the `new` keyword in `Derived`. As you said in your generic method declaration, any `T` passed to the method must be of type `Base`, so every `T` is cast to `Base`.

What happens now is that when you don't use `virtual`, you lose polymorphism, that means, even though the object is actually of type `Derived`, but cast to `Base`, the `Base` implementation of `CorrectName` is called, not - as you'd expect - the new implementation in `Derived`.

This is only called when you explicitly cast your object to `Derived`.

This has also been discussed and described here: [virtual keyword in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13856879/virtual-keyword-in-c-sharp/13856913#13856913)

Another link that might help you understand the difference between virtual and non-virtual methods could be this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table

Comment: "every `T` is cast to `Base`" - I'd expect `el as T` to perform a cast to `Derived` not `Base` (if indeed any cast at all, since it's already a `Derived`) - but `.CorrectName` to still call the `Base` version since at compile time that's the only method slot it knows about.

Comment: "where T:Base" => this means to me that T MUST inherit from Base, but it's not necessarily Base. In this example, I'm passing Derived as T, so I Expect (T)el to be the same of (Derived)el

Comment: Yes, `el` is actually a `Derived`, but thanks to `T:Base`, the method implicitly interprets `(T)el` as `(Base)el`. Actually, you're also passing a `List<T>`, which is a `List<Base>` due to `T:Base`, so every `T` from the list is treated as a `Base`.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Yet `typeof(T)` and `el.GetType()` both say `Derived`.  I think it's more correct to say that the method treats the generic type based on the constraints rather than dynamically changing the behavior to the passed in type.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Also it doesn't really matter that it's `List<T>`.  Just passing in one `T` results in the same behavior.

Comment: Added table of truth in starting post

Comment: @LucaTrazzi: And I bet that `el is Base` also returns `true`.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Of course it does, but that doesn't mean `(T)el` casts to `Base`.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Well, el is Derived which inherits Base, so, of course yes!

Comment: @Rawling: No, it was just for the sake of completeness.

Answer (score 0):

Non-virtual methods are bound at compile-time, not run-time.  At compile-time, all that can be guaranteed is that `T` is a `Base`, so the compiler binds the property accessor to the `Base` version of `CorrectName` and this will not change at run-time.  You are calling the method with `Derived` as the type parameter `T`, but others could call it with another type inheriting from `Base`, or even `Base` itself.

Virtual methods, however, will inspect the actual runtime type and call the correct overridden method.

The "table of truth" you posted is irrelevant here, since all of those are evaluated at runtime.  To prove that the compiler evaluates `T` as if it were `Base`, try the following:

```
T t = default(T);
object o = t; // works
Base b = t; // works
Derived d = t; // doesn't work
```

Comment: I like your post, but default(T) gives me null, as Derived is a reference type, I've tried by using new T(), and Derived d = t; worked

Comment: Derived d = t; shouldn't even compile as long as that code block I posted was within the Search<T> method.  I only assigned default(T) to t (yes, I could have just assigned null as well, but I am in the habit of assigning default(T) if I'm just initializing a variable of a generic type) so the code was compilable (except for the last line).  I didn't mean for it to have any meaning at runtime.

Comment: I was able to access a computer and test this, and I do in fact get `error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'T' to 'YNAB.Derived'` when I try to compile that code.