# Override Keyword in C#

Tags: c#

I have the following classes:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication8
{
    public abstract class Employee
    {
        public virtual void Show()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("from base.");
        }
    }

    public class Manager:Employee 
    {
        public void Show()
        {

            Console.WriteLine("from child.");
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var man=new Manager();
            man.Show();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Here I haven't use any `override` keyword for the method `Show()` in the derived class `Manager` but the code is running ok. So what is the actual use of `override` keyword.

Comment: try Employee man = new Manager(); and Manager man = new Manager(); with and without override instead of var man = new Manager(); and see if you still have a question.

Comment: The key point here is how the variable defined in *compile-time*. When it is already referenced as `Manager` (using `var` in your case), the compiler knows to call `Manager.Show`. *Polymorphism* comes into play when you refer to `man` as the base type (`Employee`), now the `virtual` keyword tells the compiler to check for possible overridden methods in *runtime* (typically using a vTable http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're not overriding the original method, you're [hiding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691135%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) it. This is also possible, but maybe not what you want or what you'd expect, as you lose [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)). I'll give an example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var man=new Manager();
    man.Show();
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

This is you code and outputs "From child". The following, when using "override" would also output "From child". In your case it will not.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var man=new Manager();
    (man as Employee).Show();
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

---

A similar question was asked here: [virtual keyword in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13856879/virtual-keyword-in-c-sharp/13856913#13856913). While it doesn't address the `override` keyword, the problem class is about the same.

---

Real life example of when polymorphism is useful. I had to write an application to calculate the bonuses for *all* employees in a company based on their roles. As you did, I had an employee class with a `public virtual double CalculateBonus();` method and several classed derived from that.

Thanks to Polymorphism, all I had to do is iterate the `List<Employee>` of all employees, regardless of their roles, and call the `CalculateBonus` method, as polymorphism made sure that always the overrides were called.

Without override, the bonuses would all have been 0, as that was the default result for `CalculateBonus` in the class `Employee`.

Comment: @haim770 - he's using [hiding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691135%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) in a technical sense.

Comment: Pssh to implementation/subtype overriding. Interfaces (and explicit implementations) forever!

Comment: @user2864740 And re-implement shared functionality in every class...?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar SRP and DI. Although I'm not going to say 'never useful' (and a UI library is a fairly good counter example due to the inherent tree structure), I believe that most code should have a very low subtype-to-component ratio, keeping it for special cases (and school lectures). General dislike for implementaiton subtyping aside, I think this is a fairly good answer for the scope of the question - but the 'other' side of the coin (interfaces) and how such fit in with [virtual] methods and polymorhpism is often eschewed.

Answer (score 2):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebca9ah3.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173153.aspx

you would be hiding the underlaying method so you may get a compiler warning about it and use the "new" keyword in conjunction to hide the underlaying member. override is simple - you "override" the underlaying implementation detail with your own implementation

Answer (score 0):

Check the difference

```
void Main()
{
    Person instance1=new SpecificPerson();
    instance1.Execute();//Person

    SpecificPerson instance2=new SpecificPerson();
    instance2.Execute();//Specific
}

    public class Person
    {
        public virtual void Execute()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Person");
        }
    }

    public class SpecificPerson:Person
    {
        public void Execute()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Specific");
        }
    }
```

[Overriding vs method hiding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856449/overloading-overriding-and-hiding)

Comment: Does not show a `virtual` method or `override` applied. Make sure to link back with the original question/code.

Comment: So what would happen if/when `override` was used?

Comment: @user2864740 You would get Specific in both cases

Comment: Then when/why should `override` be used and what does it do vs. not specifying it?

Comment: Please read following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838553/overriding-vs-method-hiding

Comment: @user2864740 Override should be used when, well, you want to override things. See my answer for a real-life example I'm just writing down for you.